# How to modify request/response in httpcontext in the middleware of asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, middleware

The requirement is to read the request in middleware and change it contents and then pass on to the controller. And also the response sent by the controller that needs to read and modify and then further pass on to the other middleware in the pipeline.

The data coming is encrypted base64 string and in `MyMiddleware` I will be decrypting the content and passing it to the controller and for the response it will be same. In the response it will be encrypting the data. The data content type would be `application.json`

So here is the piece of code that i have found but it is not working.

**Invoke function**

```
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
{

            await ModifyRequest(context);
            await next(context);
            await ModifyResponse(context);

}
```

**Request**

```
public async Task ModifyRequest(HttpContext  context)
{
            var request = context.Request;
            var stream = request.Body;// currently holds the original stream                    
            var originalReader = new StreamReader(stream);
            var originalContent = await originalReader.ReadToEndAsync();
            var notModified = true;
            try
            {
                //decrypting the data
                var dataSource = Decrypt(originalContent);

                if (dataSource != null)
                {
                    //modified stream
                    var requestData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataSource);
                    stream = new MemoryStream(requestData);
                    notModified = false;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            if (notModified)
            {
                //putting original data
                var requestData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(originalContent);
                stream = new MemoryStream(requestData);
            }

            request.Body = stream; 
}
```

**Response**

```
public async Task ModifyResponse(HttpContext  context)
{
            var originalResponseStream = context.Response.Body;

            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                context.Response.Body = ms;
                /*
                await next(context);
               //this line of code was there when there is no seperate func for request and response
              */

                ms.Position = 0;
                var responseReader = new StreamReader(ms);

                var responseContent = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine($"PlainResponse Body: {responseContent}");

                var encryptedResponse = Encrypt(responseContent);
                var byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encryptedResponse);
                await ms.WriteAsync(byteData, 0 , byteData.Length);

                ms.Position = 0;

                await ms.CopyToAsync(originalResponseStream);
                context.Response.Body = originalResponseStream;
            }
}
```

The above piece of code is not working. One is not sending the content to the controller and other is not writing it in context. Please Help

Comment: How are you registering the middleware and when?

Comment: @SebastianGrunow in the startup file `app.UseMiddleware<MyMiddleware>()` after `app.Authorization()` and before `app.Endpoints()` ... also in the Configure Services, im adding `services.AddSingleton<MyMiddleware>()`

Comment: According to the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/write?view=aspnetcore-5.0) you need a class implementing an `Invoke` method. You don't need to register it as a service though.

Comment: @SebastianGrunow so if I remove the `services.AddSingleton<MyMiddleware>()` ... it will work?

Comment: I cannot tell you that, because I do not have the complete code of your Startup and your Middleware. Please follow the documentation or provide more information on your classes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, I hope this will suffice.

It all depends on how you send your body and how it's interpreted by your application.

- What content-type are you sending the request with?
- When reading the body stream what result do you get?
- Is it the result you looked for?

Lets assume you use application/json content-type and you're sending a base64 encrypted object. First you'd have to extract the base64 string of the object from the original content, decrypt, convert it to json (if it isn't already is) and then read it as stream passing it to the body.

'